# Infinite group acting differentiably on continuous space

Tags: group-theory, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, lie-groups, mathematical-modeling

I am interested in infinite groups $G$ that act on $\mathbb{R}^n$, with some informal properties:

1. For each $g \in G$, the map $x \mapsto gx$ is smooth and differentiable with respect to $x$.
2. For each $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, the map $g \mapsto gx$ is smooth and differentiable with respect to $g$.

Is there a standard concept that is a reasonable match to this or way to formalize this?

Should I perhaps be looking at Lie groups?  I confess I've tried learning about them and the examples look like a match but even understanding the definition of a Lie group requires machinery that I am not familiar with.

I realize this is specified in a somewhat vague and imprecise way.  I have the sense that my situation falls within some well-studied mathematical concept, but I'm not entirely sure what.

Comment: How did this question arise?

Comment: It's only a matter of time before you stumble into the Hilbert-Smith conjecture, so yes, you'll want to know about Lie groups :)

Comment: You need to make sure that differentiation with respect to $g \in G$ makes sense.  For this, you need a Lie group.

Comment: Also, "smooth and differentiable" is a little redundant.

Comment: @Shaun, I'm trying to formalize and generalize some special cases I'm looking at (e.g., $G$ is the group of translations, $G$ is the group of rotations, etc., where they act on images), and I was wondering if there was a clean mathematical framework that I could view them as special cases of and maybe get some insight from.

Comment: @Randall, thank you, I appreciate that.

Comment: The usual condition to require is joint smoothness, i.e. smoothness of the map $G\times R^n\to R^n$ sending $(g,x)$ to $gx$.

Answer (score 1):

The right general concept seems to be the one of a Lie group, but in many cases the concept of a matrix group is sufficient. To study matrix groups, you observe that the invertible $n\times n$-matrices form an open subset of $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ so the standard concepts of analysis can be applied to them. Matrix groups are then defined as subgroups in there which are closed in the sense of topology. (This is a condition that is very easy to verify in most cases.) A fundamental theorem then says that such a matrix group is a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb R^{n^2}$. Hence in contrast to Lie groups, it suffices to understand submanifolds of Euclidean spaces rather than abstract manifolds, which makes things much easier from a technical point of view. There are several books that develop the theory of matrix groups on a relatively elementary level.